# How i can copy reverse of a map to another map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, copy

For example map1 is gaving values 1 to 10 with some address(begin to end).
i want to have values 10 to 1 with corresponding address in map2(begin to end)

```
map<long , int* > v;
map<long , int* > rv;

int i,a[10];
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
a[i] = i+1;
v.insert(pair<long, int *>(i+1,&a[i]));
}
itr = v.begin();
while(itr != v.end())
{
 cout << itr->first << " "<<itr->second;
 cout << endl;
 itr++;
}
rv.insert(v.rbegin(),v.rend());
cout << "copied array: "<<endl;
itr = rv.begin();
while(itr != rv.end())
{
cout << itr->first << " "<<itr->second;
cout << endl;
itr++;
 }
```

i tried above one but am getting values 1 to 10 only..my expected values 10 to 1.
please help me to find out....

Comment: pair<long,int *> tempPair; long x = 0; int* p = NULL; map<long,int *>::reverse_iterator r = v.rbegin(); while ( r != v.rend() ) { x = r->first; p = (int*)r->second; cout << x<< " "<<p; cout << endl; tempPair(x,p); rv.insert(tempPair); r++; } i tried like this but for this am getting error "error: no match for call to '(std::pair<long int, int*>) (long int&, int*&)' compilation terminated "

Comment: @Raj: The error in your comment is because you're defining `tempPair` too early, in C style, before you actually have an initial value. Just write `pair<long,int* > tempPair(x,p)` to define it when you do have the initial value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

STL map is an ordered container. The order of items that you get during the iteration is independent of the order in which you insert the items into the container.

The order of iteration is determined by two things:

- The value of the key, and
- The `Compare` class passed as the template parameter to the `map`

You can iterate the map in reverse order (your code snippet shows that you already know how it is done). The performance penalty for reverse-iterating a map, if any, is negligible. You can also provide a non-default `Compare` (`std::greater<long>` instead of the default `std::less<long>`) to have the default order of iteration altered.

Comment: "You can also provide a non-default Compare". An implementation of that solution [is here](http://ideone.com/6phnN).

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible because `std::map` is *ordered* associative container. If you want to preserve order of insertion use other containers such as `std::list` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Maps sort by increasing value (as dictated by operator< ), so no matter how you insert the elements, they will be returned in sorted order. You are certainly doing the insertion in reverse, but every element placed is being duly sorted into proper ascending order.